Issue with Criteria within access query?
I'm trying to write a query that when run will check if a record is overdue by atleast 10days, and if so display it, if not don't. However i am encountering issues with the criteria field for one of the fields
I've got a custom field that calculates the DueDate and calculates if it is currently 10 or more days overdue. The expressions are as follows:
DueDate:
DueDate: DateAdd("d",Switch([Priority]="A - 24 hours",1,[Priority]="A- 24 hours",1,[Priority]="B - 72 hours",3,[Priority]="B- 72 hours",3,[Priority]="C - 5 working days",5,[Priority]="C- 5 days",5,[Priority]="D > 5 working days",14,[Priority]="D > 5 days",14,[Priority]="0-Urgent",-365),[Received])

OverdueBy10:
OverdueBy10: IIf([Priority]="0-Urgent",IIf(DateDiff("d",[DueDate],Date())-365>=10,"Yes",""),IIf(DateDiff("d",[DueDate],Date())>=10,"Yes",""))

For context, i have the due date take 365 days from Urgent samples so it filters them to the top for another form. I believe i have compensated for this in the OverdueBy10 expression, if not please correct me.
My Query is structured as shown in the image below:

SQL of the above Image:
SELECT [Sample Submission].[Lab Batch ID]
    ,[Sample Submission].[IRIS Batch ID]
    ,[Sample Submission].Requester
    ,[Sample Submission].Samples
    ,[Sample Submission].Runs
    ,[Sample Submission].Method
    ,[Sample Submission].[Instrument Specific]
    ,[Sample Submission].Priority
    ,DateAdd("d", Switch([Priority] = "A - 24 hours", 1, [Priority] = "A- 24 hours", 1, [Priority] = "B - 72 hours", 3, [Priority] = "B- 72 hours", 3, [Priority] = "C - 5 working days", 5, [Priority] = "C- 5 days", 5, [Priority] = "D > 5 working days", 14, [Priority] = "D > 5 days", 14, [Priority] = "0-Urgent", - 365), [Received]) AS DueDate
    ,[Sample Submission].[Drop-Off date]
    ,[Sample Submission].Comments
    ,[Sample Submission].Received
    ,[Sample Submission].Started
    ,[Sample Submission].Finished
    ,IIf([Priority] = "0-Urgent", IIf(DateDiff("d", [DueDate], DATE ()) - 365 >= 10, "Yes", ""), IIf(DateDiff("d", [DueDate], DATE ()) >= 10, "Yes", "")) AS OverdueBy10
FROM [Sample Submission]
WHERE (
        (([Sample Submission].Method) LIKE "*CFPP*")
        AND (([Sample Submission].Received) IS NOT NULL)
        AND (([Sample Submission].Finished) IS NULL)
        )
ORDER BY DateAdd("d", Switch([Priority] = "A - 24 hours", 1, [Priority] = "A- 24 hours", 1, [Priority] = "B - 72 hours", 3, [Priority] = "B- 72 hours", 3, [Priority] = "C - 5 working days", 5, [Priority] = "C- 5 days", 5, [Priority] = "D > 5 working days", 14, [Priority] = "D > 5 days", 14, [Priority] = "0-Urgent", - 365), [Received])
    ,[Sample Submission].Received
    ,[Sample Submission].Started DESC;

When structured exactly like it is seen in the image above it runs perfectly fine. However, it shows every record that meets the defined criteria within the query, and fills in the correct response to the OverdueBy10 expression, as shown below:

I only want it to show the records where the response to the expression OverdueBy10 is Yes. I have attempted to put =Yes, ="Yes", ="* Yes *", Yes and Is Not Null in the criteria for this field and each time i do it asks for an input for the DueDate.
I'm unsure as to why it is asking for this information, can anyone help me understand why, and help with a potential solution, even if the best way forward if to use VBA?
Thanks in advance,
Ben

Please [edit] your post with the SQL form of your query. Right now you show the Design view of query. From the little you show and describe, it sounds like your calculated expression is not being used in a WHERE clause or criteria cell of Design view to filter records.

@Parfait, I have updated to include the SQL view, Apologies if its not formatted in an understandable way. Please let me know if there's a better way to upload the code for your viewing.

Unfortunately you can't use calculated query columns (DueDate) for further calculations in the same query (or for sorting, as you see in the SQL).
To avoid repeating non-trivial calculations over and over, I suggest:

Create a base query that calculates DueDate
Create a second query, based on the first one. Here you can work with DueDate as you like - for further calculated columns, criteria, sorting.

This sort of thing becomes much easier if you use a server database that supports Common Table Expressions (CTE). There you can do this step by step in one database view.

Unrelated note: the fact that you need to check for
Switch([Priority] = "A - 24 hours", 1, [Priority] = "A- 24 hours", 1, etc.
tells me that you should normalize this column - in the main table this should be a foreign key to the priority lookup table. Not the priority string.

Hi Andre, Thanks for the information, I feared that was the case with calculated columns. To Confirm, if i was to make a DueDate Query and bring this into another Query where i created the OverDueBy10 field would i them be able to use the Criteria part of the query to filter out anything under 10 days?
As for the Unrelated note, Surely even if this was a foreign key for the purposes of the query it would still need a switch function so it would know how many days to add on based on the given priority? Or am I misunderstanding?


Yes (I'm rather sure at least). 2. No, I meant "A - 24 hours" vs. "A- 24 hours". If both can appear in your priority column, you have a problem. -- Yes, the Switch would still be needed, but it would be much cleaner. -- Or you could put the translation from priority to days into the lookup table, and get the value from there using a Join.


Hi Andre, I have implemented what you suggested regarding the separation of the two queries. I can confirm that you can use criteria element of the query under the OverDueBy10 field. Thanks for your help.
